# Reading and comparing data from Arduino Uno EEPROM

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I'm trying to read compare data from EEPROM (Arduino UNO). Reading is working fine but comparing it using the '==' operator is not working as expected.

```
//string 'True' is already stored in EEPROM

int addr = 0;
char value = EEPROM.read(addr);

Serial.println(value);// this line successfully prints the letter 'T'

// but this function is not working
if (value == "T") {
  Serial.println("foo");
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with EEPROM ... this is a question about comparing strings

Comment: I have a problem like I that did you finally fix it. I will be glad if it worked.[![Thats the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqUP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqUP.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a HUGE difference between `"string"` and `'c' 'h' 'a' 'r'`.

You are comparing address of string `"T"` with the numerical value of character `'T'`.

The expression: `if (value == 'T')` will be much better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I read and compare the first letter of the string stored at addr = 0; ?

Comment: @ShyamMohan  You have to use `'T'` instead of `"T"` to compare value with...